# R - creating dataframe from colMeans function

Tags: r, dataframe

I've been trying to create a dataframe from my original dataframe, where rows in the new dataframe would represent mean of every 20 rows of the old dataframe. I discovered a function called colMeans, which does the job pretty well, the only problem, which still persists is how to change that vector of results back to dataframe, which can be further analysed.

my code for colMeans: (matrix1 in my original dataframe converted to matrix, this was the only way I managed to get it to work)

```
a<-colMeans(matrix(matrix1, nrow=20));
```

But here I get the numeric sequence, which has all the results concatenated in one single column(if I try for example as.data.frame(a)). How am I supposed to get this result back into dataframe where each column includes only the results for specific column name and not all the averages.

I hope my question is clear, thanks for help.

Comment: You can wrap with `data.frame(Col1=a)` to get a single column, if we want separate columns `as.data.frame.list(a)` which is the same as `data.frame(as.list(a))`

Comment: This only names a column with all results. I am looking for a solution where each new column would include only observations connected with it, not als results/rows

Comment: Have you tried the `as.data.frame.list(a)`? Anyway, it works for me `m1 <- matrix(1:20, ncol=4);a <- colMeans(m1); str(as.data.frame.list(a))#
'data.frame': 1 obs. of  4 variables:`

Comment: This works, yes. But when I try a<-colMeans(m1,nrow=2) , it says nrow=2 is unused argument?

Comment: Because, `?colMeans` doesn't have the `nrow` argument.  It is in `?matrix`.

Comment: Oh. So how am I supposed to take mean of every 20 rows ? You 've answered my question though. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean the column means for every 20 rows?

Comment: You can do `do.call(rbind,lapply(split(1:nrow(m1), (1:nrow(m1)-1) %/%20 + 1), function(i) colMeans(m1[i,,drop=FALSE])))`

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I thought it could be done directly with colmeans. Thanks again.

Comment: Another option is `rowsum(m1, group=as.numeric(gl(nrow(m1), 20, nrow(m1))))/20`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the `methods('as.data.frame')`, `as.data.frame.list` is an option to convert each element of a `vector` to columns of a `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame.list(a)
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(1:20, ncol=4, dimnames=list(NULL, paste0('V', 1:4)))
a <- colMeans(m1)
```