# R - Turn the results of colmeans into a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting

I was trying to create a dataframe from the results of the colMean function, but the result would always be weird. There has been previous discussion, (see:[R - creating dataframe from colMeans function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691530/r-creating-dataframe-from-colmeans-function)) but it when I implement the solution suggested, I get an extremely long data frame. It has a lot of columns, but now only one row, instead of having one column that has many rows.

```
temporary<-data.matrix(tempdb[,2:5])
temp2<-(as.numeric(colMeans(temporary),na.rm=T))
trgdphts<-c(trgdphts,temp2)
```

This is the code that I used.

Comment: What is `trgdphts`.  If it is a `data.frame`, just do `cbind(trgdphts, temp2)` BTW, you don't need to wrap with `as.numeric` (as it is already numeric - may be you want to strip off the attribute names?)

Comment: I need as.numeric to strip the colMeans function to remove the attribute names, as you mentioned, but as.numeric doesn't actually wrap.  'trgdphts' is a dataframe, is there any advantage in turning it into a matrice? 
cbind seems to work, but the formatting is really weird. It repeats a couple rows, and it also repeats the entire dataframe multiple times by the rows. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Please check the structure of the `trgdphts`.  As we don't have a reproducible example, it is not clear though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem to be that I had to clean up the variables. 
After deleting everything, then rerunning the new code, it cleaned everything up. As it turns out, the functions were being run on the stale data and the stale data was never overwritten.

Thanks to Akrun for helping out. His advice inadverdently made me discover the problem.